# "I work {on/with/in} a team"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am wondering which of the following sentences is more used or even correct? What is this called? Word-choice, collocation or something else?

1. > I work **on** a team.
2. > I work **with** a team.
3. > I work **in** a team.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Prepositions like *on*, *with*, and *in* are indicative of the writer's intent.  In your example sentences

> I work on a team.

the preposition *on* means that the subject works as a member of a team.

> I work with a team.

the preposition *with* means that the subject works in a cooperative way, although it could also indicate membership of a team.

> I work in a team.

the preposition *in* in this case seems to mean location within a team, but this does not convey the same sense of participation suggested in the first two examples.

As to whether this is a matter of word choice or collocation, it is word choice to convey intent.  Collocation most usually refers to several words that are often used together (e.g., *making my bed*, *bar of soap*, *burst into tears*).  Collocation for your examples might be something like *work team* or perhaps *work in tandem*.

Comment: Good answer, but maybe a better description of "in": 1) the person works as part of a team rather than working alone, or 2) similar to "on", but "in" might signify a minor role, or as a member of a component of a large team.

Answer (score 3):

> *I work **on** a team*

- means the person is a member of the team.

> *I work **with** a team* means I contribute my knowledge as a member

- means the person is helping a team in some way, but may or may not be a member of the team. For example, suppose my company sells widgets to hospitals, and the hospital has a team of installers who will be installing the new widgets in each room. If I am training those installers, I might say, “I am working with the installation team” even though I’m not a member of the installation team.

> *I work **in** a team*

- If I heard someone way this, I would assume they simply meant they worked as a member of the team; it sounds like it’s talking about membership more than location. A different answer says this is uttered more often in British English, which may be true. People might also use the expression *work in teams* to describe an approach to solving a problem; for example, a teacher might say to the class, “I want you to work in teams of three as you try to solve this problem.”

Answer (score 2):

- I work on a team = I manage/control/influence a team.
- I work with a team = I collaborate/cooperate with a team.
- I work in a team = I am one of that team

Answer (score 0):

- I work on a team = Used in American English
- I work in a team = Used in British English
- I work with a team = cooperate with a team